# C: How can I make it so scanf() input has one of two formats?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to do this program, which takes two triangles and compares them.

Basically everything works just fine except the part, where user inputs the initial data. My main problem is that one of the conditions is that user can input either lengths of three sides of the triangles or X,Y coordinates of three vertexes.

---

I need it to work like either of these:
This input means that user used lengths of sides:

```
{ 5 , 5 , 5 }
```

This input means that user used X,Y coordinates of vertexes:

```
{ [ 1 ; 1 ] , [ 3 ; 1 ] , [ 2 ; 2 ] }
```

---

Here is my code how I tried to solve it, but for some reason if user inputs using the vertex the first condition, which checks whether it's not side lengths, messes everything up.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a, b, c, A[2], B[2], C[2];
    char s;

    if(scanf(" { [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] }%c", 
            &A[0], &A[1], &B[0], &B[1], &C[0], &C[1], &s) != 7 && s != '\n') {
        s = ' ';

        if(scanf(" { %lf , %lf , %lf }%c", &a, &b, &c, &s) != 4 && s != '\n') {
            printf("error\n");
            return 1;
        }

    }

    // rest of the code...

    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I swap these two conditions than it switches and it works only if user inputs using the vertex...

Is it possible to make it somehow simply work like this?

Comment: I would read the whole line, decide what kind of data it is, and then parse it with `sscanf`.

Comment: Multiple questions on SO are asking about this data format, including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145987/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132823/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037182/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034556/ — all these are asking about the same "new to SO in Autumn 2018" data format in one guise or another.

Comment: This the canonical question for this format, but there are minor variants in people's perceived requirements, and if the answer you're seeking is not here, look at the questions listed under "Linked" on the right. There are at least 9 questions (including this one) on the topic. The format is almost, but not quite, like JSON. Amongst other differences, this format uses a semicolon `;` where JSON would use a comma `,`. It also lacks the names for name/value pairs within the object (`{ … }`) notation in JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It far better to use `char buf[big_enough * 2]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)` to read the *line* and then parse it, perhaps with `sscanf(buf, " { [ %lf ...` and `sscanf(buf, " { %lf ...`.

---

Yet if code is obliged to stay with `scanf()`:

OP's first `scanf(" { [ %lf ...` consumes the `'{'` expected in the 2nd `scanf( " { %lf ...`

Instead:

```
if(scanf(" { [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] }%c", 
        &A[0], &A[1], &B[0], &B[1], &C[0], &C[1], &s) != 7 && s != '\n') {
    s = ' ';

    //    no  {
    //        v
    if(scanf(" %lf , %lf , %lf }%c", &a, &b, &c, &s) != 4 && s != '\n') {
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

---

Preferred `fgets()` way:

```
// Form a reasonable, yet generous buffer
#define I (50 /* rough estimate of characters use to read a double, adjust as needed */)
//                          { [ 1 ; 1 ] , [ 3 ; 1 ] , [ 2 ; 2 ] }\n\0
#define LINE_SIZE_EXPECTED (4 + I+3+I  +7  +I+3+I  +7  +I+3+I+6)
char buf[LINE_SIZE_EXPECTED * 2]; // Lets us use 2x for extra spaces, leading zeros, etc.

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // Consider using "%n" to detect a complete scan and check for no trailing junk
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, " { [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] } %n",
      &A[0], &A[1], &B[0], &B[1], &C[0], &C[1], &n);
  if (n && buf[n] == '\0') {
    // successful scan
  } else {
    n = 0;
    sscanf(" { %lf , %lf , %lf } %n", &a, &b, &c, &n);
    if (n && buf[n] == '\0') {
      // successful scan
    } else
      // both scans failed
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `sscanf`.

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a, b, c, A[2], B[2], C[2];
    char *s = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    getline(&s, &n, stdin);

    if(sscanf(s, " { [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] , [ %lf ; %lf  ] }", &A[0], &A[1], &B[0], &B[1], &C[0], &C[1]) != 6
        && sscanf(s, " { %lf , %lf , %lf }", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {

        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // rest of the code...

    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need to capture the return value from `sscanf()` in both calls so the rest of the code knows which data to look at.  However, reading a line and then scanning it twice if necessary is the way to go.

Comment: Also add some other return value checks.

Comment: Only checking the return as in  `scanf() == 6` will not 1) insure the line ends with `"] }"` nor 2) does not have other unexpected trailing text.

Comment: Just one small thing : `getline` is not standard C, it's POSIX.