# Handling blank spaces with scanf() function in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have following problem. I would like to scan three points from scanf in the following format: `{[4;-1],[7;1.5],[4;4]}`. My code looks like this:

`scanf("{[%lf;%lf],[%lf;%lf],[%lf;%lf]}", &a1, &a2, &b1, &b2, &c1, &c2)`

Now, I am actually testing for this to be correct conversion to further work with it. But I would like to allow user to input something like this

`{ [ 4 ; -1 ] , [ 7 ; 1.5 ] , [ 4 ; 4 ] }`

or even

```
    {  [ 


     4 ; 

     -1 ] ,  [ 7 ;                         1.5 ] , [   4 ; 4 


] }
```

so the scanf() still is able to give me 6 correct conversions. What should I do?

Comment: Multiple questions on SO are asking about this data format, including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145987/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132823/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037182/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034556/ — all these are asking about the same "new to SO in Autumn 2018" data format in one guise or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow for white-spaces, a white-space before each non-white-space.

```
// "{[%lf;%lf],[%lf;%lf],[%lf;%lf]}"
" { [%lf ;%lf ] , [%lf ;%lf ] , [%lf ;%lf ] }"
```

Code can also add a space before `"%lf"`, but that does not change functionality as that specifier already consumes optional leading white-space.

```
" { [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] }"
```