# How to use scanf() for 2 correct inputs in C

Tags: c

I have a program which takes 2 different formats of input, the first one is coordinates of 3(so 6 double numbers) points of triangle, the second one is the length of each side of the triangle (so 3 double numbers).

First one is in format such as: `{ [ 1.5; 2 ], [3;4.2], [ 0.5 ; 0.6 ] }`

Second one could be: `{ 5, 4.7, 3.2 }`

How do I recognize, which one is inputted, without asking it explicitly and doing the scanf only once? 
Thanks!

Comment: You can share your code with us

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, the `scanf` family of functions is not very good with complex input or to recognize different type of inputs. For this my recommendation is to do some research about [*regular expressions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: while(n) {  
                                                                                                                                       scanf("%ld %ld",&a,&b);
 }
 scanf("%ld %ld %ld ",&e,&f.&g);          // n is no of input supposed u want 3 than n=3;

Comment: Use `fgets` then use `sscanf`.

Comment: **please not again**

Comment: Please use google search or something first. You're the fourth from your class to ask this within 12 hours or so.

Comment: Multiple questions on SO are asking about this data format, including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145987/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132823/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037182/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034556/ — all these are asking about the same "new to SO in Autumn 2018" data format in one guise or another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` with `sscanf` to achieve your requirements.

Make sure you are using format specifier for `sscanf` as your input even missing one single space cause the `sscanf` to aborting the scanning.

```
  char buf[100];
  double ptx1,pty1,ptx2,pty2,ptx3,pty3;
  double side1,side2,side3;

  fgets(buf,sizeof buf,stdin);

  int ret = sscanf(buf, " { [%lf; %lf ], [%lf;%lf], [ %lf ; %lf ] }", &ptx1,&pty1,&ptx2,&pty2,&ptx3,&pty3);

  if (ret < 6)
  {
      ret = sscanf(buf, " { %lf, %lf, %lf }", &side1,&side2,&side3);
      if (ret < 3) printf("wrong input\n");

      fgets(buf,sizeof buf,stdin);
      ret = sscanf(buf, " { [%lf; %lf ], [%lf;%lf], [ %lf ; %lf ] }", 
      &ptx1,&pty1,&ptx2,&pty2,&ptx3,&pty3);

      if (ret < 6) printf("wrong input\n");
  }
  else
  {
      fgets(buf,sizeof buf,stdin);
      ret = sscanf(buf, " { %lf, %lf, %lf }", &side1,&side2,&side3);
      if (ret < 3) printf("wrong input\n");
  }
```