# Trying to tweak sscanf() to ignore \n and \t

Tags: c, c89

I'm developing a triangle calculation and trying to tweak my `sscanf` to ignore spaces, newlines `\n` and tabs `\t`. How can I do that?

I have:

```
if(sscanf(str, "{ [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] }", &x_1, &y_1, &x_2, &y_2, &x_3, &y_3) == 6)
```

which perfectly works for inputs like these:

```
1) {[0;0],[19;10],[0;10]}

2) {     [  0 ; 0],             [12;0],[0    ;10]     }
```

but it doesn't work for something like this

```
1) {
[
0
;
15
]
,   [   112 ;   0   ]   ,[112;15]}
```

What do I need to fix?

Comment: Did you get your `str` from `fgets()`? `fgets()` stops reading at the first newline ...

Comment: if (!fgets(str, 100, stdin))
    {
        // error
    }

Comment: So what class is this?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `sscanf()` largely ignores white space by default.  A white space in the format string matches zero or more white space characters — blanks, tabs, newlines.  All but three of the conversion specifications ignore leading white space anyway — the three exceptions being `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` — so with all the white space in your format string, neither blanks nor tabs should affect the conversion, unless there is white space before the first `{` (which you could manage by adding a space in the format string before the `{`).  The problem, therefore, is probably not in the `sscanf()` but in the characters in the data.

If you are reading the data with `fgets()`, you'll need to accumulate the multiple lines into a single string buffer.  If you replaced `sscanf()` with either `scanf()` or `fscanf()`, then your format string would read the newlines as needed (but both would leave any newline after the close brace `}` to be read by future input operations).  When `sscanf()` processes the data, the string must contain all the requisite characters, nominally up to the end `}` though up to the last digit of the sixth number would be sufficient.

Given this code — where the third string represents what you say is in your third multiline data (I'm assuming that the leading `1)` and `2)` plus space are noise in the question since the format string does not attempt to parse those):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char *data[] =
{
    "{[0;0],[19;10],[0;10]}",
    "{     [  0 ; 0],             [12;0],[0    ;10]     }",
    "{\n[\n0\n;\n15\n]\n,   [   112 ;   0   ]   ,[112;15]}\n",
};
enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DATA; i++)
    {
        printf("String: @@%s@@@\n", data[i]);
        double x_1 = -9.9, y_1 = -9.9;
        double x_2 = -9.9, y_2 = -9.9;
        double x_3 = -9.9, y_3 = -9.9;
        int rc = sscanf(data[i], "{ [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] }",
                        &x_1, &y_1, &x_2, &y_2, &x_3, &y_3);
        printf("rc = %d: ", rc);
        printf(" 1 = (%.1lf,%.1lf)", x_1, y_1);
        printf(" 2 = (%.1lf,%.1lf)", x_2, y_2);
        printf(" 3 = (%.1lf,%.1lf)", x_3, y_3);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
String: @@{[0;0],[19;10],[0;10]}@@@
rc = 6  1 = (0.0,0.0) 2 = (19.0,10.0) 3 = (0.0,10.0)
String: @@{     [  0 ; 0],             [12;0],[0    ;10]     }@@@
rc = 6  1 = (0.0,0.0) 2 = (12.0,0.0) 3 = (0.0,10.0)
String: @@{
[
0
;
15
]
,   [   112 ;   0   ]   ,[112;15]}
@@@
rc = 6  1 = (0.0,15.0) 2 = (112.0,0.0) 3 = (112.0,15.0)
```

As you can see, all three scan operations are successful.  That suggests that what you think you've got as the third (multiline) string isn't what you've actually got.

I recommend doing a byte-by-byte dump of the data that fails, to see where the problem is.  Also notice that I capture and print the return value from `sscanf()`; that will help you determine where the faulty character is.  And note that `sscanf()` has no way to tell you that it failed to match the final `]` or `}` in the format string — you'll never know whether those were matched OK with the current format.

Comment: As usual a comprehensive, correct, helpful answer. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, `fgets` doesn't get you the whole thing but only a line at a time. As an alternative to concatenating multiple `fgets` reads, how about processing your input char by char and using `}` as termination:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t get_tuple(char s[], size_t sz)
{
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (i < sz-1) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
                s[i] = (char) c;
                ++i;
                if (c == '}') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (i < sz) {
        s[i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[512];
    double x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3;
    size_t len;
    len = get_tuple(s, 512);
    while (len > 0) {
        printf("%s\n",s);
        if(sscanf(s, "{ [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] }", &x_1, &y_1, &x_2, &y_2, &x_3, &y_3) == 6) {
            printf("read: x_1=%f, y_1=%f, x_2=%f, y_2=%f, x_3=%f, y_3=%f\n", x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3);
        }
        else {
            printf("scanf failed\n"); /* error */
        }
        len = get_tuple(s, 512);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Test

#### Input file

```
{[0;0],[19;10],[0;10]}

 {     [  0 ; 0],             [12;0],[0    ;10]     }

 {
[
0
;
15
]
,   [   112 ;   0   ]   ,[112;15]}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./main<test.txt 
{[0;0],[19;10],[0;10]}
read: x_1=0.000000, y_1=0.000000, x_2=19.000000, y_2=10.000000, x_3=0.000000, y_3=10.000000
{[0;0],[12;0],[0;10]}
read: x_1=0.000000, y_1=0.000000, x_2=12.000000, y_2=0.000000, x_3=0.000000, y_3=10.000000
{[0;15],[112;0],[112;15]}
read: x_1=0.000000, y_1=15.000000, x_2=112.000000, y_2=0.000000, x_3=112.000000, y_3=15.000000
```