# C scanf requested format

Tags: c, validation, input, scanf

I need to `scanf` input in my C program. I did it like this:

```
scanf("{[ %lf; %lf],[ %lf; %lf],[ %lf; %lf]}", ...)
```

but it doesn't work for some expected inputs. It must work f.e. for

> {[0;0],[10;10],[15;15]}

as well as for

> { [ 4 ; -1 ] , [ 7 ; 1.5 ] , [ 4 ; 4 ] }

or

[image]

But it needs to `printf("Bad input.\n")` if some `{ } ; , [ ]` is missing or extra.

Comment: This looks like a problem that would be better served by a simple parser that gets each of these tokens one at a time.

Comment: There's a course out there that's added this syntax.  This is at least the fifth question on the topic.  One relevant Q&A is [Trying to tweak `sscanf()` to ignore `\n` and `\t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132823/).  Basically, put a blank before each character that must be matched literally in the format string — `scanf(" { [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] }", …)`, where the blanks before the `%lf` conversion specifications are optional but symmetric (`%lf` skips white space anyway).  The other question uses `sscanf()`, but the issues are similar.

Comment: If you put spaces everywhere such as `int n = scanf(" { [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] , [ %lf ; %lf ] }", . . .);` both your examples work and `scanf` returns `6` which you ***must always check***. Edit - not the first to observe this.

Comment: Multiple questions on SO are asking about this data format, including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145987/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132823/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042562/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037182/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034556/ — all these are asking about the same "new to SO in Autumn 2018" data format in one guise or another.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, it's not (quite) JSON.  JSON would use a comma where this uses a semicolon.  See: https://json.org/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to ignore whitespace, so add spaces to your format where it might occur:

```
scanf(" { [%lf ;%lf ] , [%lf ;%lf ] , [%lf ;%lf ] }", ...)
```

The only place you don't need it is immediately before `%lf` as that specifier automatically skips and ignores whitespace.  Be sure to check the return value to ensure you matched 6 values.  Unfortunately this will not tell you if the trailing `]` or `}` is missing.  For that you can add an extra `%n` specifier at the end and check to make sure it gets set:

```
int end = 0;
if (scanf(" { [%lf ;%lf ] , [%lf ;%lf ] , [%lf ;%lf ] }%n", ..., &end), end > 0) {
    // successful read
} else {
    // error
}
```